# Add multiple element in array

Tags: arrays, c

```c
#include <stdio.h>
 
int main () {

int []={1,2,3,7,8};    // add element after 3 --> 4,5,6 (condition that i don't know position of 3 in array)


for(int i=0,i<10;i++)
{
    printf("%d\n",n[i]);
}
   return 0;
}
```

i want output 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8
but remember in case i don't know the position of 3 or 7 in array

Comment: You know, your function `largest_number` doesn't do anything that is visible after returning from it, do you?

Comment: Your program outputs 9 on my machine. Did you try debugging your program?

Comment: If the value is dynamic, you can sort the array and return how many values you want from the first.

Comment: You can sort the array in descending order (e.g., bubble sort can be implemented using a nested for loop and one if condition) and print the first n numbers of the sorted array. If your array does not contain any duplicates then those will be the n largest numbers in the array.

Comment: @tzig you are right it's my typing mistake
and i do not debugging because i not learn it

Comment: variables are valid in the array value ?
int a,b,c;
int array[3] = {a,b,c} it possible ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#include <stdio.h>

void swap(int *xp, int *yp)
{
    int temp = *xp;
    *xp = *yp;
    *yp = temp;
}
 
// A function to implement bubble sort
// n = len of tab
void bubbleSort(int arr[], int n)
{
   int i, j;
   for (i = 0; i < n-1; i++)     
 
       // Last i elements are already in place  
       for (j = 0; j < n-i-1; j++)
           if (arr[j] > arr[j+1])
              swap(&arr[j], &arr[j+1]);
}


int main()
{
    int len = 10;
    int top_number_count = 3;
    int data[10] = {1, 11, 3, 4, 5, 20, 7, 8, 9, 10};
    int temp[10];
    
    // copy the tab for dont change any value
    
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        temp[i] = data[i];
    }
    // sort the new tab
    bubbleSort(temp, len);
    
    // print the top number 
    // top_number_count is the count of max number you want
    for (int i = len - top_number_count; i < len; i++)
        printf(">%d\n", temp[i]);
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: excellent vote my question if you want

Answer (score 1):

As the number of large values to be displayed may vary, sorting the array is the best choice. There are different techniques of sorting. For this program I shall use the "bubble sort"(if you wish to learn other sorting techniques, check [this](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/sorting-algorithms/)).

Once the array is sorted in descending order(largest to smallest), we can specify the number of large values we need. The program below displays the first 3 largest numbers.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int data[10] = {0, 12, 90, 8, 1, 2, 7, 9, 11, 10} ;
    int MaxElements = 10 ;


    int endBoundary = MaxElements - 1 ;
    for(int index = 0 ; index <= MaxElements-1 ; index++)
    {
        for(int counter = 0 ; counter < endBoundary ; counter++)
        {
            if(data[counter] < data[counter+1])     // then swap the values
            {
                int temp = data[counter] ;

                data[counter] = data[counter+1] ;
                data[counter+1] = temp ;
            }
        }

        endBoundary-- ;
    }


    // displaying the first 3 largest numbers
    int numOfValuesSought = 3 ;
    for(int count = 0 ; count < numOfValuesSought ; count++)
    {
        printf("%d\n", data[count]) ;
    }

    return 0 ;
}
```

Comment: excellent
vote my question if you want